# Is there any way to obtain postgreSQL database timezone from Java code?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, timezone, jdbctemplate

I have Java Spring Boot application. I use HikariDataSource to connect to postgreSQL database. I use jdbcTemplate to send sql queries to database.
I want to get postreSQL database timezone from its settings, but I only obtain my local JVM timezone.

I have already tried such SQL queries:

```
show timezone
```

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names WHERE abbrev = current_setting('TIMEZONE')
```

```
SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE')
```

But all these queries returned me my local timezone, not database timezone.
How can I get postgreSQL database timezone setting in Java Code? Please, help

Answer (score 0):

To get the PostgreSQL database timezone setting from Java code, you can execute a SQL query directly on the database using `JdbcTemplate`. However, keep in mind that PostgreSQL does not have a direct SQL command to retrieve the timezone setting. PostgreSQL uses the operating system's timezone by default, and you might need to check the system timezone if no explicit timezone is set in the PostgreSQL configuration.

Assuming you have a `JdbcTemplate` instance, you can execute the following query to get the PostgreSQL database's timezone setting:

````
```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DatabaseTimeZoneResolver {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseTimeZoneResolver(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public String getDatabaseTimeZone() {
        // Query to retrieve PostgreSQL timezone setting
        String sql = "SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE')";

        // Execute the query and get the timezone setting
        String timezone = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, String.class);

        return timezone;
    }
}
```
````

In this code, `DatabaseTimeZoneResolver` is a Spring component that uses `JdbcTemplate` to execute the SQL query. The `getDatabaseTimeZone()` method executes the query `SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE')` to retrieve the database timezone setting and returns it as a `String`.

Make sure that your `JdbcTemplate` bean is properly configured in your Spring application context. If your application is still returning the JVM timezone, it's possible that the PostgreSQL database is indeed using the system timezone, and you might need to check the operating system's timezone setting where PostgreSQL is installed.

Additionally, if you want to set a specific timezone for your PostgreSQL database, you can modify the PostgreSQL configuration file (usually `postgresql.conf`) and set the `timezone` parameter. After modifying the configuration, you need to restart the PostgreSQL server for the changes to take effect.